# Obtain end of period timestamp in Pandas when using Grouper

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where one column is timestamps. 
Example:

```
                week                     Energy        Value
1152 2018-01-09 00:00:00                  None        0.000000   
1153 2018-01-09 00:10:00                  None        0.000000   
1154 2018-01-09 00:20:00                  None      104.000000   
1155 2018-01-09 00:30:00                  None      104.049080   
1156 2018-01-09 00:40:00                  None        0.000000   
1157 2018-01-09 00:50:00                  None        0.000000   
1158 2018-01-09 01:00:00                  None       46.428571   
1159 2018-01-09 01:10:00                  None        0.000000   
1160 2018-01-09 01:20:00                  None        0.000000   
1161 2018-01-09 01:30:00                  None      113.846154   
1162 2018-01-09 01:40:00                  None      126.108374   
1163 2018-01-09 01:50:00                  None        0.000000   
1164 2018-01-09 02:00:00                  None       35.398230   
1165 2018-01-09 02:10:00                  None        0.000000   
1166 2018-01-09 02:20:00                  None        0.000000   
1167 2018-01-09 02:30:00                  None       71.937984   
1168 2018-01-09 02:40:00                  None        0.000000   
1169 2018-01-09 02:50:00                  None        0.000000   
1170 2018-01-09 03:00:00                  None       30.877193   
1171 2018-01-09 03:10:00                  None        0.000000
```

Now I am grouping it on that column, using `pd.Grouper`, but it returns datetimes corresponding to the *end* of the grouping period. This is my query

```
df = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key=timestamp, freq='W'), 'ID'])
```

Returns:

```
week                   Count      
2018-01-07               984  
2018-01-14               566  
2018-01-21               725  
2018-01-28               815  
2018-02-04               774  
2018-02-11               648  
2018-02-18               807  
2018-02-25               804  
2018-03-04               967  
2018-03-11               953
```

This is already enormously confusing, because using `freq='W'` returns the regular Monday-to-Monday weeks, ie., weeks *ending* on a Sunday, rather than week *starting* on a Sunday, as I would have assumed. Of course, [the documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#anchored-offsets) makes no sense, because all it says there is "weekly frequency (Sundays)".

My primary question is, how can I make the timestamp column (post-grouping) return the timestamp corresponding to the *start* of the period? This is necessary, because I need to merge this dataframe with another dataframe where periods are generated using `pd.date_range(start, end, freq='W-MON')`. I cannot merge it on the end timestamp, as the latter does not return a week end, rather, it returns whatever `end` is, which may be the middle of a week.

As an aside, anyone know why the behaviour of `freq` is different for `pd.Grouper` and `pd.date_range`? The latter returns a Monday-to-Monday week, but with `freq='W-MON'`, while the former uses `freq='W'` for the same. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You simply want to use the `label` argument of `pandas.Grouper`, which tells it to use the left boundary for labeling when you provide a `freq` argument. Here's how the labeling week changes with and without that argument for the `df` you provided.

```
import pandas as pd

df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='week', freq='W-MON', label='left')]).Value.max()
#week
#2018-01-08    126.108374
#Freq: W-MON, Name: Value, dtype: float64

# Without label, it sets the label as the 
df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='week', freq='W-MON')]).Value.max()
#week
#2018-01-15    126.108374
#Freq: W-MON, Name: Value, dtype: float64
```